# bootstrap navbar 'active' loses persistence if click on page

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

This bootstrap navbar `active state` works great when clicked on, but if I click anywhere else on the page the `active state` turns off, it loses persistence. How can I fix this so that it only loses persistence when another navbar link is clicked on? Using `bootstrap.min.js` to drive the active links. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SquareGiraffe/qdj4qo0u/

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#welcome">Welcome</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#4">Four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#5">Five</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#6">Six</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#7">Seven</a></li> 

          </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is that bootstrap dosen't see this as a possibility.

A work around would be to add this. I only have a JQuery solution on hand,you could use plain javascript as well

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $('li a').click(function (e) {
            $('a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });

});
```

and this css code

```
.active { color: #fff!important;}
```

This will fix your issue. Though it isn't the prettiest approach.

Comment: I tried this and haven't got it working yet: Here's another fiddle: ` http://jsfiddle.net/SquareGiraffe/u68k5kmq/ `